# Use multithread in c++ and qml

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, bluetooth, qml

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc,argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    BlueToothdevice d;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("device", &d);
    qDebug()<<"main thread:"<< QThread::currentThreadId();
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/assets/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

BlueToothdevice.h

```
class BlueToothdevice : public QObject { balabalabala }
```

BlueToothdevice.cpp

```
balabalabala
```

main.qml

```
...
Text {
    id: bloodglucoseText2
    text: device.bdsugar
    font.pixelSize: 6 * dpi
}
...
```

how can I move object "d" defined in main.cpp to another thread?  I still want to use object "d" without changing.

Comment: try this [link](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)

Comment: Thanks, but my point is use object "d" in qml just like "device.bdsugar" because I have many function in class BlueToothdevice. The link you gave can't solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Define properties and invocable methods in your Qt class.

```
// Define the property bdsugar, accessible from Qml
Q_PROPERTY(bdsugar READ getBdSugar WRITE setBdSugar NOTIFY on BdSugarChanged)

// Define the method bdsugar, callable from Qml
Q_INVOKABLE QString bdsugar( return my_bdsugar; ) const;
```

But it is not necessary to move the object **d** to another thread (Or I did not understood the question).